# How can I derive a voltage equivalent without affecting the output?

Tags: voltage, analog, diodes, signal-processing

[image]
In the above schematics, I want to make the equivalent of the circuit on the left side. What I mean is I want to derive V2 from V1 and get rid of using two supplies. I want to derive V2 from V1 by using only resistors.

My first modification attempt on the right side with output2 is not exactly outputting as in output1. You can see the difference in the output waveforms. I tried to obtain V2 by voltage divider method. But obviously in this case it is not right this way.

How can I derive output2 exactly same with output1 by using resistors and eliminating V2? What is the methodology?

edit: if not possible with only resistors, extra diodes or transistors also allowed. but i don't want to use a voltage regulator.

Comment: What's the source impedance of your voltage source? And do you really not have any DC supply available?

Comment: assume V1 is an ideal voltage source with zero source impedance.  only one supply should be used which is V1. aim is to derive V2 from V1 with no output distortion.

Comment: Is this a homework question of some sort? This seems like a bit of an XY problem, but it's possible by rectifying V1 and regulating it.

Comment: no its not. im trying to learn deriving voltages for nodes from a single voltage source. instead of using several supplies.

Comment: as i wrote i want to achieve it only by using resistors, not with voltage regulators. imagine you need 2.84V for a node. there is no voltage regulator at that voltage. by voltage dividers, resistors it is more adjustable. for example with a poti.

Comment: Well, resistors are linear elements and cannot store energy, so I don't think you'll be able to do it with resistors, but if you can use capacitors and diodes, that will make things easier.

Comment: oh V1 is AC i should have made it DC

Comment: Okay I edited my question. There is no AC now

Comment: Well, just adjust the lower resistor of the voltage divider then (R6). Something like 1.5kΩ perhaps.

Comment: i'll try tomorrow and reply you. gotta go now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fduR4F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: i will check it today and reply you. how did you come up with the idea?

Comment: Q1 is in a very common configuration that is used for voltage regulation.

Comment: In the original circuit, the diode acts like a switch, which is very non-linear, so the behavior cannot be emulated with just resistors alone in general (unless you restrict the operating range such that the diode is either always on or always off, for example).

Comment: I couldn't figure out a clean solution with just diodes and resistors. I can see too "ugly" possibilities. One is to emulate the voltage source with voltage divider like you did. You have to make the resistance much lower to minimize error (distortion). But the error rate is inversely proportion to the power waste. For example, to get 1% error, you waste around 100 times the power. Second is to connect 8 or 9 diodes in series to emulate the 5V plus 1 diode voltage drop. But diodes have dependency on temperature and current, the dependency are multiplied by 8 or 9 by having that many in series.

Comment: it works good. so this PNP with R3 R4 forms a constant voltage.  many text books doesnt show these important points..